# If every continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ is bounded, then $K$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I'm trying to solve the following question from the [real analysis](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Echparkin/gre/GREProb.pdf) section:

> 1. Let $K$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R^n$ where $n > 1$. Which of the following statements must be true?
>
> (I) If $K$ is compact, then every continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ is bounded.
>
> (II) If every continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ is bounded,
> then $K$ is compact.
>
> (III) If $K$ is compact, then $K$ is connected.

The proof for (I) is standard. I'm trying to see (II) by contradiction.

Is it possible to frame a proof for (II) along these lines:

Suppose $K \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is not compact. Then there exists an open cover $\mathcal C$ that has no finite subcover. But $f: K \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. (...) Contradiction.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I know the Heine-Borel theorem. A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Is it helpful here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, this is a standard result. Now, suppose every continuous real valued function defined on $K$ is bounded. In particular, the function $f(x)=||x||$ is bounded on $K$, hence $K$ is a bounded set.

So we only have to prove $K$ is closed. Well, suppose it isn't. Then there is some point $y\in\overline{K}\setminus K$. Define $f:K\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{||x-y||}$. This is a continuous function which isn't bounded, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks but why are we specifically choosing $y \in \bar K \setminus K$? Wouldn't $f(x)$ be unbounded even if $y \in K$? (Only the domain of $f$ would have to exclude $y$ to make it defined.)

Comment: But this wouldn't give us a contradiction. We are assuming that every continuous function defined on $K$ is bounded, not that every continuous function defined on $K\setminus\{y\}$ is bounded. This is a big difference. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$ the set $[0,1]$ is compact, but $[0,1)$ isn't, and there are continuous functions defined on $[0,1)$ which are unbounded.

Comment: Actually I'm not even sure how to see that $f(x)$ as you defined is unbounded.

Comment: By definition, if $y\in\overline{K}$ then there is a sequence $(y_n)\subseteq K$ such that $y_n\to y$. This means $||y_n-y||\to 0^+$, and thus $f(y_n)=\frac{1}{||y_n-y||}\to\infty$. So $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would just like that to add that if the range was the reals endowed with the bounded metric, $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$, then the statement is not true for metric spaces even if the $Dom(f)$ satisfied the Heine-Borel property.