# If every continuous real-valued function defined on K is bounded, then K is compact?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

**Theorem**: Let $K$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}.$ If $f(K)$ is bounded for *any continuous* function $f:K\to\mathbb{R}$, then $K$ must be compact.

> The same theorem, written in quants: $\forall f\in C(K): $
> $f(K)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ => $K$ is
> compact.
> $K$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $C(K)$ is the set of
> all continuous functions defined on $K$

I have seen other solutions, but they use **too advanced** a level for me. Can you give a proof of this theorem, referring only to results **not beyond introductory real analysis**?

P.S. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would proceed with contradiction. Assume $f(K)$ is bounded for all continuous $f$, but $K$ is *not* compact. Then either $K$ is unbounded or $K$ isn't closed, by Heine Borel. Taking $f$ to be the identify shows that $K$ must be bounded, so it must be the case that $K$ isn't closed. Can you use this assumption to find a continuous function $f$ such that $f(K)$ is unbounded, giving you a contradiction?

Comment: Are we assuming that $K \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: @RobertShore The question says "... $f$ defined on a subset $K$ of $\Bbb R$" and
 "$K$ is a subset of  $\Bbb R$".

Comment: @RobertShore, no, I am interested in the case of n=1

Comment: @MatthewH. Thanks! I will try it

Comment: "Not beyond introductory analysis"? But what is your (or better,  if possible: what are your equivalent) definition(s) of a compact subset of $\Bbb R,$ then? And of a closed subset? Do you have any problem with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3791854/386889)? (for $n=1$ if you like).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668905/1093844

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee That link is of far too advanced level for the OP (contrarily to the one proposed just before)

Comment: @AnneBauval
1) The compact subset was introduced as follows:
A set $A$ is called compact if a finite set can be extracted from any of its covers by open sets.
Then the theorem was introduced:
$K$ is a compact if $K$ is bounded and closed

2) A subset is called closed if its complement is an open set

Comment: @AnneBauval, yes the OP should check the link that you have shared. I just shared that link in case the OP wants to explore it in future.

Comment: @Kottoamatsukami thanks for this quick answer. All this only for $A\subset\Bbb R,$ right? And don't you have equivalent definitions of a closed subset? Like "$A$ is closed iff for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ which converges in $\Bbb R$, the limit belongs to $A$" (this is the definition used in [the answer linked above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3791854/386889)).

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, I just asked my professor about that definition. It will be introduced in our next lecture series. Perhaps I should have waited until now, but this theorem really interested me. In other words, your definition can also be used in the proof.

Comment: Yes, it *is* used in the proof previously (twice) linked above. Can we close your post as a duplicate of it, or do you prefer an answer which sticks to your first definition of a closed subset?

Comment: @AnneBauval I prefer the answer for the first definition of a closed subset.

Comment: As you like. But you would have certainly been able to prove that these two definitions are equivalent (it is nearly "automatic writing").

Comment: I just realized that my only reason for not considering that link as a duplicate was imaginary! Its accepted answer actually does not use the sequential characterization of closedness as I claimed. It only relies on your definition, i.e. on the fact that if $F$
 is not closed, there exists a $y∉F$
 such that $F$
 meets every open interval around $y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We work by contradiction.  We take as our hypothesis that every continuous function on $K$ is bounded.  We assume $K$ is not bounded and demonstrate a contradiction.  Then we assume that $K$ is not closed and demonstrate another contradiction.

As noted above, if $K$ is unbounded, the identity function on $K$ also is unbounded.

If $K$ is not closed, then $A=\Bbb R \setminus K$ is not open.  Choose $x \in A$ such that there is no open ball around $x$ that is contained in $A$.  Such an $x$ must exist because $A$ is not open.  That means every open ball around $x$, no matter how small, has non-empty intersection with $K$, so you can get as close as you like to $x$ and still stay within $K$.

Then $f: K \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(y)= \dfrac{1}{y-x}$ is continuous and unbounded on $K$.  The function $f$ is continuous on $K$ because it's continuous on $\Bbb R \setminus \{x \}$ and $x \in A \Rightarrow x \notin K$ by the definition of $A$, so $K \subseteq \Bbb R \setminus \{ x \}$.  It's unbounded because we just showed that we can make $\vert y - x \vert$ arbitrarily small and still stay within $K$, which means we can make $\vert f(x) \vert =\left \vert \dfrac{1}{y-x} \right \vert$ arbitrarily large within $K$.

In higher dimensions, use the function $\dfrac {1}{d(y, x)}$ to the same effect.

Thus, if all continuous functions on $K$ are bounded, it follows that $K$ must be closed and bounded; in other words, compact.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is how does it follow that the set K is closed?

Comment: If $K$ is not closed, its complement is not open, so there’s at least one point, which I’m calling $x$, that’s in the complement (which I’m calling $A$) but not in the interior of $A$.  Use that point to construct a function that’s both continuous and unbounded on $K$, contradicting our hypothesis that there is no such function.